# Pandas Pivot Table with 3 levels of Multi-indexing

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I have tried every way imaginable to take this data frame

```
import pandas as pd

dataDict = {'State': ['Idaho', 'Wyoming', 'Montana', 'Idaho', 'Idaho', 'Wyoming', 'Montana', 'Idaho', 'Idaho', 'Wyoming', 'Montana', 'Idaho'],
            'City': ['Boise', 'Jackson', 'Missoula', 'Sandpoint', 'Boise', 'Jackson', 'Missoula', 'Sandpoint', 'Boise', 'Jackson', 'Missoula', 'Sandpoint'],
            'Years': [2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012],
            'PizzaOrdered' : [3000, 50, 1000, 78, 3250, 75, 1250, 82, 4000, 98, 4100, 92],
            'TacosOrdered' : [5000, 65, 1900, 88, 5780, 78, 2128, 90, 6125, 87, 5999, 95]
            }
testData = pd.DataFrame(data=dataDict)
```

[image]

And transform it to this

[image]

I have tried pivots, groupby, set_index, stacking, unstacking and I can get close but not quiet to this example I have provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `melt` before `unstack`

```
df_final = (testData.melt(['State', 'City', 'Years'], var_name='Ordered')
                    .set_index(['State', 'City', 'Ordered', 'Years'])['value']
                    .unstack())

Out[54]:
Years                           2010  2011  2012
State   City      Ordered
Idaho   Boise     PizzaOrdered  3000  3250  4000
                  TacosOrdered  5000  5780  6125
        Sandpoint PizzaOrdered    78    82    92
                  TacosOrdered    88    90    95
Montana Missoula  PizzaOrdered  1000  1250  4100
                  TacosOrdered  1900  2128  5999
Wyoming Jackson   PizzaOrdered    50    75    98
                  TacosOrdered    65    78    87
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `pivot_table`, then `'stack`:

```
testData.pivot_table(index=['State','City'], columns='Years').stack(0)
```

Output:

```
Years                           2010  2011  2012
State   City                                    
Idaho   Boise     PizzaOrdered  3000  3250  4000
                  TacosOrdered  5000  5780  6125
        Sandpoint PizzaOrdered    78    82    92
                  TacosOrdered    88    90    95
Montana Missoula  PizzaOrdered  1000  1250  4100
                  TacosOrdered  1900  2128  5999
Wyoming Jackson   PizzaOrdered    50    75    98
                  TacosOrdered    65    78    87
```